# How to manage overlapping yticks and legends in a heatmap plot in julia?

Tags: plot, julia, legend, overlapping, yticks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXoZD.png)

I'm trying to create a **heatmap featuring yticks on both the left and right** side of each row. While plotting, I've encountered an issue where the **yticks on the right side overlap with the legend**. Despite attempting commands like "right_margin," I haven't been successful in adjusting the position of the yticks or the legend—they only seem to add space to the right side of the legend.

Could you offer any advice on how to rearrange the yticks and legends in this plot? Below is the code I've been working with.

Thanks a lot!

```
using Plots
using Statistics
using DelimitedFiles
using StatsPlots
using DataFrames
using Plots.PlotMeasures
using CSV
using LaTeXStrings

function total_plot_compared_new()
        Catchments=["Feistritz", "Palten", "Gailtal", "Silbertal", "Defreggental", "Pitztal" ]
        Catchments_n=["Feistritztal", "Paltental *", "Gailtal *",  "Silbertal *", "Defreggental", "Pitztal" ]

        obj_title = [L"Obj_{tot}", L"E_{NSE,Q}",L"E_{NSE,log(Q)}", L"E_{VE,Q}", L"E_{NSE,FDC}", L"E_{RE,AC1}", L"E_{NSE,AC90}", L"E_{NSE,RC}", L"E_{AE,SC}"]
        s_calibrations_path = "/01 Model /Calibrations/"

        cal_performance_s = CSV.read("01 Model/04 Results/Calibration/Total/S_Calibration.csv", DataFrame, decimal='.', delim = ',', header=false)
        cal_performance_ns = CSV.read("01 Model/04 Results/Calibration/Total/NS_Calibration.csv", DataFrame, decimal='.', delim = ',', header=false)
        val_performance_s = CSV.read("01 Model/04 Results/Calibration/Total/S_Validation.csv", DataFrame, decimal='.', delim = ',', header=false)
        val_performance_ns = CSV.read("01 Model/04 Results/Calibration/Total/NS_Validation.csv", DataFrame, decimal='.', delim = ',', header=false)
        cal_performance_dif = zeros(6,9)
        val_performance_dif = zeros(6,9)

        for (c,cm) in enumerate(Catchments)

                for (o, ob) in enumerate(obj_title)
                    cal_performance_dif[c,o] = cal_performance_ns[c,o] - cal_performance_s[c,o]
                    val_performance_dif[c,o] = val_performance_ns[c,o] - val_performance_s[c,o]
                end
        end

        cal_performance_s = Matrix(cal_performance_s)
        cal_performance_ns = Matrix(cal_performance_ns)
        val_performance_s = Matrix(val_performance_s)
        val_performance_ns = Matrix(val_performance_ns)

        hm_s = Plots.plot()
        hm_c_s = Plots.heatmap(cal_performance_s, legend=false, c=:RdBu, clims=(-1,1), title="Calibration Sr,cal", titlefont=font(18), xmirror=true)
        for y in 1:1:6
            for x in 1:1:9
                t = round(cal_performance_s[y,x],digits=2)
                    annotate!(x,y,string(t), :white)
            end
        end
        xticks!([1:9;], ["","","","","","","","","",""], xtickfontsize=14)
        yticks!([1:6;], Catchments_n, ytickfont=font(14))
        display(hm_c_s)

        hm_v = Plots.plot()
        hm_v_s = Plots.heatmap(val_performance_s, c=:RdBu, clims=(-1,1), title="Evaluation Sr,cal", titlefont=font(18), ymirror=true)

        for y in 1:1:6
            for x in 1:1:9
                t = round(val_performance_s[y,x],digits=2)
                annotate!(x,y,string(t), :white)
            end
        end
        xticks!([1:9;], ["","","","","","","","",""], xtickfontsize=14)
        yticks!([1:6;], ["F","E","D","C","B","A"], ytickfontsize=14, tickfonthalign=:left)
        total_s = plot(hm_c_s, hm_v_s, layout=(1,2), size=(2500,1000))

        hm_ns = plot()
        hm_c_ns = heatmap(cal_performance_ns, c=:RdBu, clims=(-1,1), legend=false, title="Calibration Sr,clim,adapt", titlefont=font(18))
        for y in 1:1:6
            for x in 1:1:9
                t = round(cal_performance_ns[y,x],digits=2)
                    annotate!(x,y,string(t), :white)
            end
        end
        xticks!([1:9;], ["","","","","","","","",""])
        yticks!([1:6;], Catchments_n, ytickfont=font(14))

        hm_ns = plot()
        hm_v_ns = heatmap(val_performance_ns, c=:RdBu, clims=(-1,1), title="Evaluation Sr,clim,adapt", titlefont=font(18), ymirror=true, ytickfontsize=14)
        for y in 1:1:6
            for x in 1:1:9
                t = round(val_performance_ns[y,x],digits=2)
                    annotate!(x,y,string(t),:white)
            end
        end
        xticks!([1:9;], ["","","","","","","","",""])
        yticks!([1:6;], ["L","K","J","I","H","G"])
        total_ns = plot(hm_c_ns, hm_v_ns, layout=(1,2), size=(2500,1000))

        hm = Plots.plot()
        hm_c_d = heatmap(cal_performance_dif, c=:RdBu, clims=(-0.2,0.2),title="Calibration", legend=false,  titlefont=font(18), ytickfont=18)
        for y in 1:1:6
            for x in 1:1:9
                t = round(cal_performance_dif[y,x],digits=2)
                    annotate!(x,y,string(t), :black)
            end
        end
        xticks!([1:9;], obj_title, xrotation=45, xtickfont=font(14))
        yticks!([1:6;], Catchments_n, ytickfont=font(14))

        hm_v_d = heatmap(val_performance_dif, c=:RdBu, clims=(-0.2,0.2), title="Evaluation", yaxis=nothing, titlefont=font(18), legend_position=:outertopright)

        for y in 1:1:6
            for x in 1:1:9
                t = round(val_performance_dif[y,x],digits=2)
                annotate!(x,y,string(t), :black)
            end
        end
        xticks!([1:9;], obj_title, xrotation=45, xtickfont=font(14), ymirror=true)
        yticks!([1:6;], ["R","Q","P","O","N","M"], ytickfont=font(14))

        total_dif = Plots.plot(hm_c_d, hm_v_d, layout = grid(1,2, widths=[0.46, 0.54]), size=(2500,1100), bottom_margin=30px, top_margin=15px)

        l=@layout[a b{0.55w}; c d{0.55w};e f{0.55w}]
        total_both = Plots.plot(hm_c_s, hm_v_s, hm_c_ns, hm_v_ns, hm_c_d, hm_v_d, layout=l, size=(2500,3000), bottom_margin=10mm, top_margin=1mm)
    
        Plots.savefig("01 Model/04 Results/Calibration/Total/Total_compared_Cal_Val.png")
        
    return
end
```

[image]

Comment: Try doing `Plots.gr_cbar_offsets[] = (0.05, 0.07)` before plotting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Dan! Unfortunately still receive the error: gr_cbar_offsets not defined in expression etc. Any advice?

Comment: Oh really, which version of Plots are you using? (I'm getting `Plots v1.39.0`)

Comment: Aah that's it, I was working from an older version of Plots. I've updated it and it works - thanks :) !!

Do you by any chance also know what commands to use to increase the annotation font size and cbar_ticks? I am working with GR as a backend. I've tried several commands that I found online, but none seem to work.